# Accessing Service Running on Azure Windows Machine on Specific Port

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have an Azure Windows Virtual Machine where I have enabled the Inbound Rule Port 8080 under Network Security Group. However, when I try to check the connectivity from my Windows Machine to Azure VM it fails. I used the below command.

```
>telnet <public_ip_address_of_the_vm> 8080
Connecting To XX.XXX.XXX.XXX...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8080: Connect failed
```

Note: The VM is enabled with Public IP Address. How to further troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is ensure the VM is **running**.  Then, look at is the **Effective Security Rules** for the NIC in question.

[image]

If the VM has multiple NICs you need to look at the effective rules for each nic (they can be different).

To run a quick test to determine if traffic is allowed to or from a VM, use the [IP flow verify](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/diagnose-vm-network-traffic-filtering-problem) capability of Azure Network Watcher. IP flow verify tells you if traffic is allowed or denied. If denied, IP flow verify tells you which security rule is denying the traffic.

If there are no security rules causing a VM's network connectivity to fail, the problem may be due to:

- Firewall software running within the VM's operating system
- Routes configured for virtual appliances or on-premises traffic. Internet traffic can be redirected to your on-premises network via forced-tunneling. If you force tunnel internet traffic to a virtual appliance, or on-premises, you may not be able to connect to the VM from the internet. To learn how to diagnose route problems that may impede the flow of traffic out of the VM, see [Diagnose a virtual machine network traffic routing problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-routing-problem).

Full Troubleshooting Docs with [step-by-step instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/diagnose-network-traffic-filter-problem).

Comment: What is the role of "Effective Security Rules" ?

Comment: You can assign NSG's at either the NIC or Subnet level. Effective security rules view returns all the configured NSGs and rules that are associated at a NIC and subnet level for a virtual machine providing insight into the configuration.